# Android Reading image names from database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is probably pretty straight forward, but I am getting no-where at the moment.
I have read through a lot of posts but have not hit the answer yet.
I have a gallery in my app,based largely on the google gallery app, with the images stored in R.drawable and the paths to the images stored in an 'Integer' array.
I have moved the image paths into a database table and am trying to read them back and so display the images, but all I am seeing is a blank gallery.
I would be so grateful if someone could point me in the right diorection here, I feel I'm going in circles.
Below is the code I use to read the items from the database:

```
//get the gallery items from the cursor
    ArrayList galleryList = new ArrayList();
    for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){
        Integer gal;
        gal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("small_img"));
        galleryList.add(gal);
    }
    myImageIds =(Integer[])galleryList.toArray(new Integer[galleryList.size()]);
    db.close();
```

This is the Integer array the names paths are read into:

```
private Integer[] myImageIds;
```

Then in the 'ImageAdapter' class I try to copy the array into the 'Integer' array mImageIds:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mImageIds = Drager.this.myImageIds;
```

As I say, this gives me an empty gallery, where am I going wrong?
Is there a different way to store the paths to the drawable directory in a database?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path to your images isn't truly an integer.  It's just referenced in that way in the R class.  I guess I said that pretty definitively, but what I'm really offering is a hint/clue based on what I believe to be true.  It's like R.strings.myString ... that's an "integer" too though it's just an integer reference to a string.  Make sense?

Comment: Hi Bill, I sort of get what you mean. I have tried literally everything I can think off though, I have tried reading the values back as strings, casting them from Strings to Integer, I have really run out of ideas, I have been looking at this all day.

Comment: I struggled with something similar early on.  When you're storing the value in the DB you need to store the physical path not the integer referenced in R.  getText(R...) or getString(R...) was the solution.  I don't have my development environment available to give you the exact method.

Comment: oh right, i'll have a look at that then,and tell you how I get on. thanks Bill.

Comment: Don't forget to share the love if people are helpful, up votes and check marks are equally agreeable.  I only mention it because I see that you're new.  People will more readily help you if you're supportive. :)

Comment: Will do Bill. So your saying that in my database, I want to store something along the lines of "data/images/whereever/gallery_photo_1.jpg? Do you still place images in the R.Drawable folder then, or not bother and just store the physical path to the images?

Comment: You want your app to be as small as possible.  So, it really depends on where the images are from and what they're for.  If the images are part of your application then I don't know what to tell you.  They'll already be in R.drawable and you wouldn't need that kind of reference to them.  If they're the user's images then you're on the right path.